# Why would a Windows Driver Setup program not properly install the driver but "update driver" does

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a question that has been bothering me since yesterday. I was installing windows on a desktop yesterday and I went to install a LAN driver. I went to the motherboard manufacturers site and got what I believed to be the correct driver. The installation failed. I then tried to install all of the other LAN drivers available for that motherboard. All of the installations failed. I then finally thought to go to manage hardware and "update driver". I selected the USB key I had all of my attempted drivers on. And low and behold I had internet access.

My question is this: Why? What is the difference? Why did using the setup.exe program not work yet the "update driver" option did work even though they are the same files/program?

In case it matters the OS was WIN 7 ultimate and the motherboard was ASUS a88xm-a.

Answer (score 0):

Bad hardware dude. If you check in the device manager, do you see any yellow ! marks? If you go to the properties of the device in Device Manager, if it says something along the lines of "Code 10, device cannot start", it's dead.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).